# Read a line from file and store it a string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, file-io, io

I have a .txt file like this:

```
(A+B-C+6-8)
(A*5+4)
```

And I want to read each line as a string and put them in a string array. For example, str[10] would have the string "(A+B-C+6-8)" as its elements. Then I would do something with the array, then when I'm finished and there would be a new line, the array would reset and store the next line of strings.

What function should I use? `fgets`? `fgetc`? `fscanf`? I'm really confused with all these I/O functions. Thanks!

Comment: First try something yourself, then ask showing code.

Comment: @herohuyongtao it's a string array named str, with 10 elements.

Comment: @user3206772 It has 11 chars, why 10?

Comment: @herohuyongtao oh sorry. I was just making an example. Didn't realize there were 11 characters in the first line.

Comment: It's actually twelve if you count the null-character.

Answer (score 2):

You should use fgets, to read one line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Get first line:

```
FILE* myFile = fopen("filename.ext", "r");
size_t maxNoChar = 100;
char * line = malloc(maxNoChar);
if(myFile != NULL)
{
    fscanf("%s", myFile, &line);
}
```

Comment: please, for EVERY fopen() there has to be the corresponding if(), even in an example answer.

Comment: @PeterMiehle sorry, done. :)